# $\sum \frac{(-2x)^n}{e^n}$ intervals of convergence

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

Is the interval of convergence of these infinite here?

1. $$\sum \frac{(-2x)^n}{e^n}$$
2. $$\sum \frac{nx^n(n+1)}{n!+n}$$

I check it using the root test 1., root test it's $\lim_{n\to\infty}\Big|\frac{(-2x)^n (-2x)}{e^n e} \frac{e^n}{(-2x)^n}\Big|$. So it's cancel out and no limit is here. It becomes $\frac{2|x|}{e}$ here yes? So limit is zero.

2., then this I calculate using the root test to be $\lim_{n\to \infty} \Big|\frac{x (n+2)(n!+n)}{n ((n+1)! +(n+1))}\Big|$. And limit is zero.

To summarize, if limit is zero, then radius of convergence is infinity. So the interval of convergence is infinite. Right?

Comment: For $(1)$, you didn't use the root test you used the ratio test and you forgot an important "part" of the ratio test. For $(2)$ The ratio test should solve it. Take a look at this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test and this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test

Comment: Using Root test or ratio test to determine the radius of convergence, you need to consider the limit of the root or quotient resp. of the coefficient of the power series. So $x$ here doesn’t enter the calculation.

Comment: @judgeKevin: don't forget to include absolute values in your expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first power series can be handled easily through the n-th root test, which in this case, it means that
$$S_1(x):=\sum_n(-1)^n\Big(\frac{2}{e}\Big)^nx^n$$
converges iff
$$\limsup_n\sqrt[n]{|(-1)^n(2/e)^nx^n|}=|x|\frac{2}{e}<1$$
That is, $S_1(x)$ converges iff $|x|<e/2$.

The second power series can be handle through the ratio test, which in this case, it means that
$$S_2(x):=\sum_n\frac{n(n+1)}{n!+n}x^n$$
converges iff, with $a_n=\frac{n(n+1)}{n!+n}$,
$$\limsup_n\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}|x|=\limsup_n\frac{n+2}{n(n+1)}\frac{n!+n}{n!+1}|x|<1$$
The limit
$$
\lim_n\frac{n+2}{n(n+1)}\frac{n!+n}{n!+1}=\lim_n\frac{n+2}{n(n+1)}\cdot\lim_n\frac{1+\tfrac{1}{(n-1)!}}{1+\tfrac{1}{n!}}=0$$
Therefore, $S_2(x)$ converges for all $x$.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have gotten the second one.

For the first,  by Cauchy-Hadamard, we have $r=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\dfrac1{|(-2/e)^n|^{1/n}}=e/2$.